# Is this format correct for a marquee in HTML?

Tags: html, css, marquee

I've used a marquee in my HTML document and it works fine except that it won't scroll right but that's not the problem I have. I want to know if this format is correct since I'm using a CSS sheet as well.

```
<div id="right">
<marquee direction:"right" scrollamount="3" onmouseover="this.stop();" onmouseout="this.start();"> Marquee </marquee>
</div>
```

Should I be placing the direction, scroll elements on the stylesheet? I'm a newbie at this so I'd love an explanation.

Comment: <marquee> in 2014? Note that <marquee> tag is not part of the HTML standard. If you want a flashy, disturbing, moving text in an HTML page, you should use CSS or Javascript rather than marquee.

Comment: Yes, but I was told to use a marquee by my teacher since this is a assessed task. Thanks for that though, Lie.

Answer (score -1):

I think u can use css Animation for this work. it's better solution than a marquee tag in html.